# How to extract exe file without installing it, using powershell?

Tags: powershell, cmd

I am trying to extract one .exe file without installing it. The way to do in CMD is

```
C:\Users\ramadeviA\Downloads\Setup.exe /a
```

But I want to know how to execute this in powershell. Can anybody help me.

I tried this one but it doesn't work for me

```
$CMDCOMMAND = "C:\Users\ramadeviA\Downloads\Setip.exe /a"
Start-Process $CMDCOMMAND
```

Comment: Type `help Start-Process` at a Powershell prompt.

Comment: This is also dependent on the exe you are talking about not all have switches that allow this. Using something like 7zip would also work in cases like these. Your current title does not match your question since that switch appears to be proprietary.

Comment: Don't see any reason why the first one (`path\to\file\setup.exe /a`) wouldn't work. That's valid expression in PowerShell. That would fail if there was space in path (easily fixed by: `& 'path to\file with\spaces\setup.exe' /a`).

Comment: Like @BartekB said - use the exact same command line you would use in cmd.exe, unless the path to the executable contains spaces, in which case you need the call operator (`&`) before the executable's name.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Perhaps...

```
start-process C:\Users\ramadeviA.WINMAGIC\Downloads\Setip.exe -Argumentlist "/a"
```

that should be it

Comment: start-process is unnecessary. Just run the executable.

Comment: first, there is an _ which is wrong and it does not work.